# OpenCV cv::waitKey does not work

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

Here is the sample code.

```
   cv::VideoCapture capturedVideo;
   capturedVideo.open(videoFile);
   if (!capturedVideo.isOpened())
   {
      std::cerr << "Unable to open video: " << videoFile << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   cv::Mat dispFrame;
   cv::namedWindow("Video Edit", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   while (true)
   {
      capturedVideo >> dispFrame;
      if (!dispFrame.empty())
         imshow("Video Edit", dispFrame);
      if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) // wait for key press event
      {
         puts("Key press");
         break;
      }
   }
```

However the code never flows to "Key press". I have printed the return value of `cv::waitKey` which supposed to be the ascii code of a pressed key. It is always correct. What is happening here?

Comment: My environment is a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM on top of Windows 10. I am using OpenCV 3.1.0.

Comment: You have a 30ms delay, you can try increasing that? The function returns -1 if no key was pressed in that time window.

Comment: I have tried changing that to 3000ms delay. The result is still the same. I am unable to break the loop.

Comment: can you try non-capital lettered cv::waitKey? Or did the syntax change? What happens if you use if (cv::waitKey(0) == 'q') for example?

Comment: Just a typo. In my actual code, it was small letter w. Sorry!

Comment: @zeb is there another thread with a waitKey? What happens if you use waitKey(0)?

Comment: I think you need to `&` the result of `waitKey()` with `0xff`.

Comment: Micka, nothing happened when I changed it to (cv::waitKey(0) == 'q'). And, the application is single-threaded, meaning I did not add threads. Actually, this code is all I have right now.

Comment: @zeb what do you mean by "nothing happened"? Is an image displayed? Does your application pause until you press a key? If you add @ micka (without space) in your comment I will be noticed and see your answers earlier!

Comment: @Micka What I am saying is that the character was read like before but the loop continued. I am now suspecting this might be a bug.

Comment: @Mick I think `cv::waitKey()` returns an `int` rather than a `char` and that's why it may be negative and why the `if` condition is never entered and why some folks `&` it with `0xff`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's a point, although char can be negative too ;) . At least on Windows, the returned int equals the char of the pressed key (at least for typical letters). Not sure about return values on linux though. Maybe you are right.

Comment: @zeb can you change to `int c = cv::waitKey(0); std::cout << "pressed " << c << std::endl; if(c>=0) ...` and post the cout for some keys?

Comment: Also, the window with the image displayed in it must have focus (i.e. be selected) when you press the key - it doesn't notice if you press the key when the Terminal (where you started the program from) is selected.

Comment: Can someone else try this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I was not able to break the loop even when the window with the video was on focus.